# Странные логи в access.log

Tags: nginx

Заметил интересный запрос, который прошел через один из наших серверов,

```
207.46.13.83 - - [08/Feb/2021:18:24:33 +0300] "GET /gimnastki/shemale-cumsh... .php HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
```

Полную урлу сократил (там было что-то непотребное).

Данные запросы повторяются с определенной периодичностью в течение всего дня. Судя по всему здесь есть редирект, получается, у нас есть какая-то дыра, которая позволяет делать запросы от имени нашего сервера на эти урлы?

Подскажите, что это может быть и как с этим можно бороться

Comment: «дыра, которая позволяет делать запросы от имени нашего сервера» — непонятно, на чём основан такой вывод. Просто поисковый робот по какой-то причине решил, что у вас должна быть такая страница, и решил её посетить

Comment: я сильно не уверен, что это бинговский бот.

Comment: а почему 301, куда редиректится данный запрос?

Comment: @KoVadim айпишник принадлежит сети майкрософта, как минимум (AS8075)

Comment: @sergpc а это мы у вас должны спросить, почему ваш сайт на несуществующие ссылки отвечает редиректом :)

Comment: @andreymal да, но сама трасса какая то странная-странная.

Comment: @andreymal, 
`location / {
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ^~ /api/ {
       proxy_pass https://backend;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location ^~ /wsapi/ {
       proxy_pass https://backend;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

`

Comment: @andreymal, `
location /openvidu/ {
       proxy_pass https://backend;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /wsapi/muse/ {
      proxy_pass https://backend/wsapi/uni;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
`
это настройки nginx, может я чего не понимаю, но редиректы подобных урлов не должны проходить

Comment: Хотя как вариант это может быть редирект с http на https (если поисковый робот решил посетить именно http)

Comment: к тому же, на некоторые запросы отвечает 200-ой, хотя такого нет

` 13.66.139.119 - - [08/Feb/2021:15:52:38 +0300] "GET /gruppovuha/ ... rodstvennikami.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1760 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" `

Comment: Может быть, вас взломали и "подсадили" второй сайт. Смотрите скрипты сайта, конфиг апача .htaccess (если он есть) и прочее. Если 301 редирект - это нормальное поведение вашего сайта, например кидает на главную, а не на левый ресурс - просто забейте. В интернете такое бывает. Хотите чистый лог - заблокируйте IP.